# Download git code and run scripts on virtual machine from Jenkins (window)

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have attached one virtual machine to Jenkins.

I then need to download the source code from git and run a few powershell scripts on this virtual machine with the help of Jenkins which is on a Windows machine.

Could someone please assist me with some direction on how to go about this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! Could you please bring more details about what you tried ?

Comment: Hi. Is this a proof of concept?